# Relogio JavaScript incrementar para game

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, setinterval

Eu estou criando um time em JS para contar o tempo que o usuário levará para concluir a tarefa. Estou usando `setInterval()` para rodar o time porém não estou conseguindo incrementar para mais de (1) o valor de `min()`. Este é o meu código:

```
const time = {
    min: 0,
    sec: 0,
    getSec: function(){
        this.sec++;
        if (this.sec === 59) {
            this.min=+1;
            this.sec =0;
        }else {
                if (this.sec >= 59) {
                this.sec = '00';
                this.min=+1;
            }
        }
    },
}

$sT = $('.score-panel').find('#time');
function setTime () {

    setInterval(function(){
      time.getSec();

    $sT.html(time.min + ':' + time.sec);
    },1000)
}
window.clearInterval(setTime());
```

o `if` dentro do `else` foi uma tentativa para incrementar os minutos conforme o segundos dão 59.
O `window.clearInterval()`  é para parar o tempo quando o usuário mudar de tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é a atribuição que você está fazendo. No `this.min =+ 1` você está atribuindo o valor positivo de 1, por isso sempre resulta em 1.

O sinal de `=+` é usado para atribuir o unário `+` de um valor em outro:

```
a =+ b
a = + (b)
```

Quando se utiliza o `+=` está utilizando um operador de atribuição, que vai somar mais um no valor que tem:

```
a += b
a = a + b
```

Você pode ver a diferença de valores resultantes abaixo:

```js
num = 10;
num2 = -5;
num =+ num2;
console.log("Operação com '=+' retorna " + num);

num = 10;
num2 = -5;
num += num2;
console.log("Operação com '+=' retorna " + num);
```

Comment: Mano obrigado de verdade, eu corrigir aqui e deu certo agora sim esta incrementando os minutos. Obrigado de verdade, Deus abençoe vc cara.

Comment: Eu realmente não tinha me dado conta da atribuição do `=+` obrigado cara.